# 逃げさせる vs 逃す or 逃がす

Tags: word-choice, verbs

i know 
逃す is like let someone escape (but you tried to prevent it),
and 逃がす is let someone escape (but you didn't try to prevent it)

How about the causative form of 逃げる, which is 逃げさせる？

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely need to add the furigana.

[逃]{のが}す: Unintentional - "to fail to catch".  You tried to catch something but did not succeed.  "Not catching" was not intentional though that was the result.

[逃]{に}がす: Intentional - "to set one free".  You meant to let him go.

[逃]{に}げさせる: Intentional - "to let or allow one to escape"  You meant to do so.

Comment: ? I've definitely heard 「逃すな!」 in some anime somewhere before. 使い方間違ったかな?

Comment: We do say 「[逃]{のが}すな!」 to mean "Catch it/him!".  By "unintentional", I mean to say that if you failed to catch something, that was not intentional.  You made the effort to catch it but failed as a result.

Comment: 「逃のがすな!」〜　"Don't let him get away!"

Comment: @TrevorAlexander, there are many verbs that are technically volitional verbs, e.g. they have potential forms, but their potential forms and imperative forms are more often used in negative sentences. e.g. 悲しく思わないで, 死ぬな, 失敗するな, 恥ずかしがらないで, 心配しないで, etc.

Comment: You can also say にがすな! with the same meaning (i.e. the unintentional reading).

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to leave it in hiragana... I was looking for what @dainichi mentioned.